# Vanilla JS trying to maintain execution order (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript

I am running into this problem where I am trying to create a slideshow for a project that retrieves images from an API and then displays it. I have the follow function `getPictures(id,number,callback)` that returns an *object/ array/ callback* based on the options.

To load the `picturesList`, I'm trying to dynamically expand it and it is right now a global variable which I am modifying when the `nextPicture(button)` is being clicked.

```
next.onclick = function() {
    append();
    nextPic();
};
```

The issue I am having is that when I put a conditional to check the index and to retrieve a new picturesList so that I can append to the global one, it keeps saying that the returned array is undefined.

```
function append(){
    var t;
    getPictures(pic[0].id, 7, function(response) {
      t = response.pics;
    });
    picturesList.push(t);
}
```

But the execution order is something I'm not able to control and being a Java programmer a few concepts are rather confusing. What's the best way to approach this ? I read about callbacks and promises, but none of them seem to cater to setting the global variable (picturesList)

Comment: The execution order is fine - it's your understanding of it that's causing your issue.  `t` is only set when the asynchronous call to `getPictures()` is completed, but the next line of code after that call is executed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to call `nextPic()` after the asynchronous call is complete then you can simply move the function call inside the callback...

```
next.onclick = function() {
    append();
};

function append(){
    getPictures(pic[0].id, 7, function(response) {
        picturesList.push(response.pics);
        nextPic();
    });
}
```

If you want to use the `append` function elsewhere, without calling `nextPic()` then you can add an optional callback to the function...

```
next.onclick = function() {
    append(nextPic);
};

function append(callback){
    getPictures(pic[0].id, 7, function(response) {
        picturesList.push(response.pics);
        if (callback != undefined) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```